# LiveCode negative "firstIndent" - or other way to achieve the effect ("hanging indent")?

Tags: user-interface, textfield, text-alignment, livecode

Using the `firstIndent` property on a field, I can make the start of a paragraph indent relative to the standard margin, so that if the line wraps, the continuation starts to the left of the first character on the line above.

But if I set a negative value for `firstIndent`, it has no effect.

Is there a way to achieve the effect that the line starts to the left, but if it wraps, subsequent lines are indented over to the right?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by setting a value for 'leftindent", and negative value for 'firstindent'
(note you need to specify a line number when setting leftindent)

```
set the leftIndent of line 1 of field "A" to 200
set the firstIndent of field "A" to -50
```

Comment: Excellent tip. By the way: the 'effect' that this question refers to is called "hanging indent". Perhaps the title should be edited to make it easier to search for it.

Comment: Thanks Alex - I didn't think about line properties - that does the job very nicely!

Comment: (Knud, good point - I've also edited the title of the question)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "leftindent" property of lines in a field was only introduced in LiveCode version 5.5, and that as of LC 5.5 the "firstIndent" property can now be applied to lines as well as entire fields:

```
set the firstIndent of line 2 of field "xyzzy" to -10
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - that'll be my excuse for not knowing about it!  How do firstIndent and leftIndent interact if they can both be applied to a line - do they just cancel each other out?